# How can I set the SelectedIndex property of a ComboBox that is bound to XML based on an attribute in that xml?

Tags: wpf, binding, xml-binding

I have a WPF Combobox defined as such:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="cUrls" SelectedIndex="1"  ItemsSource=" {Binding XPath=//data/endpoints/endpoint}" Margin="5" >                    
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The window is bound to an XmlDocument like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <data>
      <endpoints>
         <endpoint name="test">test url</endpoint>
         <endpoint default="true" name="production">production url</endpoint>
       </endpoints>
     <requests>
        <request >
               ...
        </request>
        <request >
                ...
        </request>
      </requests>
    </data>
```

The binding works fine and the combo box shows the items "test" and "production" and I am able to pull the right URL out of the SelectedValue property.

I would like to be able to set the `SelectedIndex` property on the ComboBox to the index of the `<endpoint>` node that has `default=true` attribute.

Can I do `SelectedIndex="{Binding XPath=}"` on the ComboBox?  If yes, what would that expression look like?  If not, what should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
      <ComboBox x:Name="cUrls" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding XPath=/data/endpoints/endpoint[@default\=\'true\']}"
```

Comment: Nope. Neither does adding /position() at the end of the XPath

Comment: That doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Matthew Try this edited snippet. I just tested something like this.

Comment: Sorry to undo your correct answer but there is a problem.  It seems that whenever I attempt to access the `SelectedItem` property on the ComboBox it is _always_ the `@default=true` element even after I change the combobox.  The value of the SelectedItem property doesn't change when I change the combobox at runtime in the UI. Any ideas?